# php curl POST with athentification

Tags: php, api, curl, post

I am having some issues with a POST request I have to send to an API.

Here is what the API is saying:

The API lets you create a new webinar by sending a HTTP POST request to
https://clevercast.com/api/v1/webinar/create
The request requires Basic Authentication, using the email address of a Clevercast user with
the necessary permissions and his password.
The request must be encoded as a Multipart form. The ‘Content-Type’ header must be set
to ‘multipart/form-data’. Its body should contain the required fields with a string value from
the table below

So went a head and wrote the following code:

```
     /* API URL */
    $url = 'https://clevercast.com/api/v1/webinar/create';
    $username = 'username';
    $password = 'password';

    /* Init cURL resource */
    $ch = curl_init($url);

    /* Array Parameter Data */
    $data = ['name'=>'Begrafenis van xxxx', 'language'=>'fr', 'start_time'=> '2020-28-12
    13:05', 'end_time'=>'2020-28-12
    13:30'];

    /* pass encoded JSON string to the POST fields */
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);    
    /* set the content type json */
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: ‘multipart/form-data'));

    /* set return type json */
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    //get info

    /* execute request */
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    /* close cURL resource */
    curl_close($ch);

    print_r($result);
```

But I always get a 404 back.

The guys from the API also sent me a sample code. It should look like that:

curl --request POST -u "username:password" -k "https://app.clevercast.com/api/v1/webinar/create/" -F name="Afscheid van XXX" -F language="nl" -F logo=@/data/funerarium-logo.png -F logo_link="https://example.com/my-funerarium/" -F poster=@/data/foto-overledene.jpg -F start_time="2020-08-04 14:00" -F end_time="2020-08-04 15:00" -F live_private_communication="questions" -F vod_private_communication="questions" -F email_questions="familie@example.com" -F sender_name="My Funerarium" -F reply_to_email="info@my-funerarium.com" -F reply_to_name="My Funerarium" -F description="Wij zijn heel verdrietig dat XXX plotseling is ingeslapen. Wij zullen altijd van je blijven houden.
Via de tab hernaast kan u een bericht achterlaten voor de nabestaanden." -F background_color="rgba(8,97,106,1)" -F panel_text_color="rgba(8,97,106,1)"

Has anybody a clue where the problem could be? Is there a way to just send the RAW curl command?

Comment: Not sure if it matters, but there is a `/` on the end of their example - `webinar/create/"`

Comment: Are the fields seen in the example curl command optional or required?

Comment: The URL that the guy sent to you is different than you are using. It begins with `app.`
`https://app.clevercast.com/api/v1/webinar/create/` and the one you are using is
`https://clevercast.com/api/v1/webinar/create`
Try to copy/paste the exact URL

Comment: thanks for noticing. Now I got an internal error and not a 404 error anymore. And to reply to RamRaider, anly the field I've put in my code are required fields.

Answer (score 0):

So apperently I was doing it semi right but they have problems with PHP at their side.

They used an other library called Raques for PHP (https://github.com/rmccue/Requests)

Now it is working as it should.

Thanks for the help .